# Installing Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, ssh, bluehost

I'm trying to install mongo with php on my bluehost server. I ssh this command:

```
>pecl install mongo
```

It goes through the whole process but at the end I get this:

```
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/home1/{myhostname}/tmp/pear/pear-build-{myhostname}P2D4wf/install-mongo-1.3.7" install
Installing shared extensions:     /home1/{myhostname}/tmp/pear/pear-build-{myhostname}P2D4wf/install-mongo-1.3.7/usr/lib64/php/modules/
running: find "/home1/{myhostname}/tmp/pear/pear-build-{myhostname}P2D4wf/install-mongo-1.3.7" | xargs ls -dils
22955452   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 {myhostname} {myhostname}   4096 May  4 23:52 /home1/{myhostname}/tmp/pear/pear-build-{myhostname}P2D4wf/install-mongo-1.3.7
22955521   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 {myhostname} {myhostname}   4096 May  4 23:52 /home1/{myhostname}/tmp/pear/pear-build-{myhostname}P2D4wf/install-mongo-1.3.7/usr
22955522   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 {myhostname} {myhostname}   4096 May  4 23:52 /home1/{myhostname}/tmp/pear/pear-build-{myhostname}P2D4wf/install-mongo-1.3.7/usr/lib64
22955523   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 {myhostname} {myhostname}   4096 May  4 23:52 /home1/{myhostname}/tmp/pear/pear-build-{myhostname}P2D4wf/install-mongo-1.3.7/usr/lib64/php
22955524   4 drwxr-xr-x 2 {myhostname} {myhostname}   4096 May  4 23:52 /home1/{myhostname}/tmp/pear/pear-build-{myhostname}P2D4wf/install-mongo-1.3.7/usr/lib64/php/modules
22955520 960 -rwxr-xr-x 1 {myhostname} {myhostname} 982160 May  4 23:52 /home1/{myhostname}/tmp/pear/pear-build-{myhostname}P2D4wf/install-mongo-1.3.7/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so'
ERROR: failed to write /usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so (copy(/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so): failed to open stream: Read-only file system)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you doing this with `sudo`?

Comment: Tried sudo and got this:
    sudo pecl install mongo
    sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
    sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
    sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: Nevermind, looks like it's a bluehost thing. I think it only works if you're a dedicated user.

Comment: yeah i can see you being able to have that level of privilege in a hosted environment !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem,

You have to have a `VPS` or a `Dedicated Server` If you are hosted at `Bluehost`

Because you need access to the `Root Directory`

Answer (score 3):

you can go directly on this link :

for the window
http://mongodbhelp.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-install-mongodb-with-windows.html

for the linux
http://mongodbhelp.blogspot.in/2014/09/blog-post.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install is using Homebrew.
Once homebrew is installed, just use `brew install mongodb`

Comment: This solution is specific to OS X only.

Comment: In case of linux you have a fork of homebrew available known as LinuxBrew.
Install that. It will work same as homebrew.